# how to pass location of private key kept at resources folder at application properties in spring boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, public-key-encryption

A private key(pk8 file) has been kept at `Resources` folder in Spring Boot application.

It is required to pass this pk8 file at application properties. It is being used at datasource url.

We are using `classpath` to provide location of file.

But it is giving error.

```
Could not read SSL key file classpath:client-key.pem
```

application properties field

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/test?ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=/etc/test/server-ca.pem&sslcert=/etc/test/client-cert.pem&sslkey=classpath:client-key.pk8
```

pk8 file at Resources folder

[image]

Error
[image]

Comment: Looks like only a file path is acceptable. You are using a resource path. Put the file in your home directory and include the full path to it. btw, you should post your error messages as text not images